# Measurement of pressure using inclined manometer

Tags: fluid-mechanics

While pressure measurement in manometers is independent of size,why do we use a reservoir that has a larger diameter than the other limb in inclined manometer?

Answer (score 0):

The q in your title does not match the q in the body.

But for an lnclined mano it is to give a more precise reading as the working distance is longer but the range is shorter.

The difference in diameters does the same thing.